# Sort table values that have been imported from Google Sheets using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, google-sheets, tablesorter

When I am importing data into a table, I am not able to use the table-sorter feature that allows me to click on table headings and automatically sort data ascending/descending. The code I use for table sorting is:

```
$(function(){
 $('#grades').tablesorter();
});
```

Is there any way that I am able to sort data that is pulled in from Google Sheets? I am assuming it is not working because the data being pulled in isn't actually being displayed in my code editor so there aren't any values to sort. I'd appreciate the help! Thanks

Here is an example of the code I am using to import cell data from Google Sheets:

```js
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

httpGetAsync('https://spreadsheet.glitch.me/?key=1JBbAHH1DFtO1r56lr94lUqd8H7qPcHncJskcPq0r96o', function(response) {
  var json = JSON.parse(response);
  document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML = json[0].Title;
  document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = json[0].Name;
  document.getElementById("Car").innerHTML = json[0].Car;

  let divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#Name, #Car"));
    divs.forEach(function(div) {
      // Convert text to number and test for positive/negative
      if ((+div.textContent) >= 0) {
        div.textContent = "+" + div.textContent;
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The problem may depend on when you call `tablesorter()`. Try instantiating the library *after* all the data from the Google sheet has been inserted in to the DOM. Also check the console for errors, just to make sure nothing's gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: Right...when you add the html after the tablesorter plugin is initialized it doesn't know you added it

Comment: @Rory McCrossan @charlietfl   okay I have moved the `tablesorter` plugin to after my sheets function in `index.html`between `<script></script>` tags at the bottom with no luck - doing this should load tablesorter after the data has been pulled in right? I have no errors in console either

Comment: Not quite as the loading of the sheet is asynchronous. You need to put it at the end of the anonymous handler function you provide to the `httpGetAsync()` call

Comment: sorted it! just moved it inside my sheets function